# Querying Records in a Database with date parameters/variables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a website/database solution with database viewing/querying rights for the administrator.

I would like to give the user the option to insert two dates, with the page then producing all orders within the selected period.

I'm aware of how to retrieve variables from a form, it's the back end stuff I'm unsure about and applying the dates to the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to maybe get you going in the right direction:

```
$results = mysql_query(
    sprintf("
        SELECT [your fields]
        FROM [your table]
        WHERE [date field] > '%s'
        AND [date field] < '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($enteredStartDate),
        mysql_real_escape_string($enteredEndDate)
    )
);
```

Edit:

Dates should be in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

Example fetch / display:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo $row['fieldName'];
}
```

You of course need to be connected to a DB for any of this to work, see [PHP Manual mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

If you are still having problems I think you need to do some reading on using PHP / MySQL, a [simple Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=php%20mysql%20tutorial&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=eca6a646aa0fe0a2&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1920&bih=952) gives a whole stack of possible reading material.

Comment: `$enteredStartDate` and `$enteredEndDate` should be in YYYY-MM-DD format. maybe you could consider using `>=` and `<=` for your WHERE clause.

Comment: After adapting your code, it seems to be working without errors, however, what is the best way to then print the selected records out?

Comment: Apologies, the code is attempting to print but I get an error saying the query is empty, even though I know there are dates of records within the period I have selected?

Answer (score 0):

use sql between operator,

```
where table.date_column_name BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will do -

```
$query = SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE create_time <= '" . $EndDate . "' and create_time >= '" . $StartDate . "';
```

where create_time is the the field in your table where you save date and time

Comment: My browser is highlighting an unexpected T_VARIABLE in this query in my code. After thinking it might be because of the 'forward slashes' in the date entries, I attempted one without slashes but the same problem occurs.